# htaccess RewriteRule just for direct file link in url, not for php scripts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i need to prevent URL direct file access through htaccess `RewriteRule` directive on my `uploads` folder, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* ../fileLink.php
```

in `fileLink.php` I check if user's logged.

But I need to let php scripts access to that folder without restrictions.

How could I disable the rule for my internal php scripts?

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Unless you fetch the files via HTTP, your PHP scripts always have access to local files.

Comment: I'm using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for displaying files and I don't kwon exactly how it fetches them

Answer (score 0):

You can this rule to forbid external url access to the folder :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /uploads/.*\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This will return a 403 error if the folder and fils are requested.

Comment: thank you! But i don't need to forbid file access, I just need to previously check for user logged.. i've added a note.